# Relative Time/date format filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any filter to show data like this:

```
5 minutes ago,
today,
yesterday,
01-01-2018 etc.
```

I researched but don't found anything like that.
`Laravel` has a function like this is called `diffForHumans()`

Comment: do a search for *"angular timeago"*

Comment: `moment(date).calendar()` ....

Comment: I think you need [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to simplify a lot of manual code

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Relative Time in [MomentJs](http://momentjs.com/)

```
moment(date).fromNow();
```

### Relative Time

```
moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 6 years ago
moment("20120620", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 6 years ago
moment().startOf('day').fromNow();        // 19 hours ago
moment().endOf('day').fromNow();          // in 5 hours
moment().startOf('hour').fromNow();       // 15 minutes ago
```